# Use of r12 register in code produced by hotspot C2 jit compiler

Tags: assembly, x86-64, jit, jvm-hotspot

I have a java code which looks like this:

```java
private volatile boolean myWriteActionPending;
void startWrite() {
  boolean prev = myWriteActionPending;
  myWriteActionPending = true;
  try {
    // acquire write lock here + do some other stuff
  } finally {
    myWriteActionPending = prev;
  }
}
```

C1 in java-11.0.14.1 generates following code for `myWriteActionPending = true`:

```
mov    eax,0x1
mov    BYTE PTR [rsi+0x5a],al
lock add DWORD PTR [rsp-0x40],0x0
```

And this for `myWriteActionPending = prev`:

```
mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rsp+0xf8]
and    edi,0x1
mov    BYTE PTR [rsi+0x5a],dil
lock add DWORD PTR [rsp-0x40],0x0
```

C2 generates this for `myWriteActionPending = prev`:

```
mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
mov    BYTE PTR [rbx+0x5a],r12b
lock add DWORD PTR [rsp-0x40],0x0
```

Since I use compressed oops r12 contains the HeapBase. What is the meaning of `mov BYTE PTR [rbx+0x5a],r12b`? How it restores the field to the original value?

Comment: A bit of context (code before these fragments) would be helpful. One possible optimization: if `myWriteActionPending` is already `true` prior to the operation, both writes are obsolete and can be omitted. Otherwise, the first write has to write `1` and the second has to write `0`, where every register whose lowest byte contains zero would be usable.

Comment: It seems like compiler indeed transformed finally block to `myWriteActionPending = true`. I thought it would emit immediate `0x0` instead of using the register with 0 lower byte. Doesn't such a transformation change semantics? The `prev` was saved because potentially there might be a recursive call to `startWrite` and in this case value of `myWriteActionPending` will be preserved. In practice it never happened. Can jit detect that?

Comment: @Holger: interesting idea that it might be using `r12b` as a convenient zero register. In this case that wouldn't actually save any bytes of code-size, though, since `mov  BYTE PTR [rbx+0x5a],  0` with an immediate 0 is the same size: no REX prefix since no regs from r8..15 are involved, but  an immediate zero byte. It *would* help if the pointer had been in any of R8..15 though, and it's not worse (except on P6-family for register-read stalls), so it would make sense for the compiler to always replace immediate zero with R12B without checking if it saved code-size or not, if it's 256-aligned

Comment: Whether the JIT can preclude recursive operations, depends on the actual contents of the `try` block and whether contained method invocations have been inlined. As said, it would be helpful to see the code of the entire method.

Comment: Generated code for the method is 2500 lines long with a lot of inlined functions. Unfortunately I cannot share the java source of it. Anyway your comment answered the original question about r12 use. Thank you!